# Why apache nutch Generatorjob takes so mutch time

Tags: apache, hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I am using apache nutch 2.3 to crawl some data from web along with hadoop 1.2.1 and hbase 0.94.14. I have already crawled some data and now when my crawler starts, it takes too much time before it start fetching. It takes about 50 minutes in generatorjob and in fetching only 1.5 hours. What is this issue.

I want to generatorjob should take minimum time and fetcher job should take maximum time.

Comment: Are you using distributed mode?

Comment: My hadoop cluster is fully distributed mode.